# How to add duplicate columns together?

Tags: bash

I have a file with:

```
1/1 1
1/1 4
1/1 3
1/2 6
1/2 2
1/2 1
```

I would like to change all the contents of the file to this:

```
1/1 8
1/2 9
```

How would I achieve this?

I have tried sed but can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 2):

Use `awk` instead of `sed`:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (e in a) print e " " a[e]}'
```